# Geoserver MBTiles plugins performance issues

Tags: geoserver, cartography, performance, sqlite, mbtiles

I am using the latest stable 2.7.2 version of GeoServer and I am trying to play with the MBTiles plugin, I have installed also WPS plugin that is needed by the MBTiles one (otherwise I got error when starting). I am using the MBTiles plugin found on community-latest because no one is found under the release folder for 2.7.2 version, however it seems to work, the only problem is that is really bad in performance (30-40s or even more for each request to be displayed). Reading MBTiles under OpenMap (BBN Technologies) or under World Wind Java (I have wrote a plugin for that) is really fast and straight forward, I don't understand why it is so slow. Could be probably something related to different projection system? My MBTiles is in EPSG 3857, but requested display projection is the same, so I suppose that no re-projection is needed....Prior to investigate on the GeoServer code for the MBTiles plugin, I would ask you if someone has experienced the same performance problem.

Taking a thread stack I see that Geoserver seems always executing this piece of code:

```
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:68)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.geotools.mbtiles.MBTilesFile.closestZoom(MBTilesFile.java:519)
at org.geotools.mbtiles.mosaic.MBTilesReader.read(MBTilesReader.java:152)
at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.read(AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.java:249)
at org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.read(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:147)
at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:227)
at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:217)
```

Comment: It probably depends on the complexity of the layer(s) you are rendering and how you have parameters like metatiling set, It is a community module so any help would almost certainly be apreciated.

Comment: How are you calling the layer?

Comment: @iant - The mbtiles are prerendered layer, so I suppose that no extra work shall be performed by the plugin apart from mapping boundbox to zoom,column,row of the tiles to be shown. Actually I am accessing to just on layer using "layer preview" of GeoServer

Comment: @BradHards - What do you mean? Do you want to know "Publish configuration"?

Comment: You are doing some kind  of GetMap or GetCoverage query. I want to know what it is.

Comment: @BradHards OK. Is this one:
wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=MBTiles:DolomitiMB&styles=&bbox=<...>&width=768&height=661&srs=EPSG:3857&format=application/openlayers

Comment: Please edit the question.